# ASP.NET/Bootstrap data- attributes aren't automatically initialized

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a basic Bootstrap accordion, see example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). I literally copied and pasted the example into a tab within a modal, but the data-toggle attribute isn't initialized, when I click on the heading it tries to go to the id URL.

I think the issue is likely with my includes, I had to activate my tabs manually when in theory the data-toggles should've worked for them as well. In other project I don't recall this being necessary.

```
$('#modalTabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show')
})
```

I have checked, and yes jQuery is initialized before Bootstrap. And I have also seen that some people had issues when `type="text/javascript"` wasn't included, but that didn't make a difference. Also multiple includes of the JS files. Still no luck. No errors in the console either.

Running with Bootstrap 3.3.6 and jQuery 2.0.3

Comment: do you check for javascript errors ?

Comment: @Aristos "No errors in the console either."